# Private Static variable get method fails with error Variable is not visible

Tags: static, private

I do not understand why I get an error in the line

```
isExecuting = false (Variable is not visible)
```

But if I comment out that line the error disappears. Thus, from the same getter, the line

```
if ( isExecuting == null )
```

compiles just fine.

Why can it not see the Static Private variable inside the IF but can see it in the IF condition itself?

--Edit -- added another screenshot from developer console that might help elaborate the problem better.

[image: Static Private Variable]

[image: developer console]

Comment: If possible can you please share the full code which you have tried?

Comment: In future, please avoid use of screenshots for code. This use 1. means text in those images is not searchable or copy/pasteable and 2. prevents partially sighted people from contributing solutions as they don't know what the code is (their screen readers may not be able to use OCR to extract such information).

Comment: you are right, will keep that in mind @phil w

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You didn't define a setter for that variable, so you cannot overwrite it.
To fix the issue just add `set;` after the `get`:

```java
private static Boolean isExecuting {
    get {
        if (isExecuting == null) {
            isExecuting = false;
        }
        return isExecuting;
    }
    set;
}
```

[Documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_properties.htm)

> If a property has only a get accessor, it’s considered read-only.